# Minimum number of special moves to sort number

Tags: algorithm, sorting, reorderlist

Given the list of numbers

```
1 15 2 5 10
```

I need to obtain

```
1 2 5 10 15
```

The only operation I can do is "move the number X at position Y".

In the above example I only need to do "move the number 15 at position 5".

I would like to minimize the number of operations but I can't find/remember a classical algorithm for that, given the operation available.

Some background :

- I'm interacting with an API for a kanban-like service.
- I have about 600 cards and some actions on our bug-tracker can imply a reordering of these 600 cards in the kanban (multiple cards can move at the same time if the priority of a project is changed)
- I can do it in 600 calls to the API but I'm trying to reduce that number as much as possible.

Comment: It looks like an _XY question_ to me

Comment: Maybe I am missing something - but what is the difference between this problem and the a "standard" sort based on swaps (like quicksort)?

Comment: "move the number X at position Y" - insertion sort?

Comment: @amit I think there is a difference between the number of comparisons needed to sort a collection and the actual number of swaps (in his case isn't actually a swap, but it's a similar principle). You need at most N swaps to sort an array, but you can do it in less, depending on the permutation cycles of the data.

Comment: I see, he's interested in minimizing only the number of swaps, not the total number of ops. Thanks @JuanLopes

Comment: "move the number 15 at position 5" is incomplete - it need to specify a destination or relative motion or something, as in "move the number X at position Y to position Z" or "move the number X at position Y N positions left" or something.

Comment: Included a proof-of-concept in my answer, please check.

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma:** The minimum number of (delete element, insert element) pairs you can perform to sort a list *L* (in increasing order) is:

> *S<sub>min</sub>(L)* = |*L*| - |*LIC(L)*|

Where *LIC(L)* is the *Longest Increasing Subsequence*.

Thus, you have to:

- Establish the *LIC* of your list.
- Remove the elements not in it and insert them back at the appropriate position (using binary search).

---

**Proof:**
By induction.

For a list of size 1, the longest increasing subsequence is of length... 1! The list is already sorted so the number of (del,ins) pairs required is

> |*L*| - |*LIC(L)*| = 1 - 1 = 0

Now let *L<sub>n</sub>* be a list of length *n*, 1 ≤ *n*. Let *L<sub>n+1</sub>* be the list obtained by adding an element *e<sub>n+1</sub>* to the left of *L<sub>n</sub>*.
This element may or may not influence the *Longest Increasing Subsequence*. Let's try to see how...

Let *i<sub>n,1</sub>* and *i<sub>n,2</sub>* be the two first elements of *LIC(L<sub>n</sub>)* **(*)**:

- If *e<sub>n+1</sub>* > *i<sub>n,2</sub>*, then *LIC(L<sub>n+1</sub>)* = *LIC(L<sub>n</sub>)*
- If *e<sub>n+1</sub>* ≤ *i<sub>n,1</sub>*, then *LIC(L<sub>n+1</sub>)* = *e<sub>n+1</sub>* || *LIC(L<sub>n</sub>)*
- Else, *LIC(L<sub>n+1</sub>)* = *LIC(L<sub>n</sub>)* - *i<sub>n,1</sub>* + *e<sub>n+1</sub>*. We keep the *LIC* with the *highest* first element. This is done by removing *i<sub>n,1</sub>* from the *LIC* and replacing it with *e<sub>n+1</sub>*.

---

In the first case, we delete *e<sub>n+1</sub>*, we thus get to sort *L<sub>n</sub>*. By the induction hypothesis, this require *n* (deletion, insertion) pairs. We then have to insert *e<sub>n+1</sub>* at the appropriate position. Thus:

> *S(L<sub>n+1</sub>)<sub>min</sub>* = 1 + *S(L<sub>n</sub>)<sub>min</sub>*
> *S(L<sub>n+1</sub>)<sub>min</sub>* = 1 + *n* - |*LIC(L<sub>n</sub>)*|
> *S(L<sub>n+1</sub>)<sub>min</sub>* = |*L<sub>n+1</sub>*| - |*LIC(L<sub>n+1</sub>*|

---

In the second case, we ignore *e<sub>n+1</sub>*. We begin by deleting elements not in *LIC(L<sub>n</sub>)*. These elements have to be inserted again! There are

> *S(L<sub>n</sub>)<sub>min</sub>* = |*L<sub>n</sub>*| - |*LIC(L<sub>n</sub>)*|

such elements.

Now, we just have to take care and insert them in the right order (relatively to *e<sub>n+1</sub>*). In the end, it requires:

> *S(L<sub>n+1</sub>)<sub>min</sub>* = |*L<sub>n</sub>*| - |*LIC(L<sub>n</sub>)*|
> *S(L<sub>n+1</sub>)<sub>min</sub>* = |*L<sub>n</sub>*| + 1 - (|*LIC(L<sub>n</sub>)*| + 1)

Since we have |*LIC(L<sub>n+1</sub>)*| = |*LIC(L<sub>n</sub>)*| + 1 and |*L<sub>n+1</sub>*| = |*L<sub>n</sub>*| + 1, we have in the end:

> *S(L<sub>n+1</sub>)<sub>min</sub>* = |*L<sub>n+1</sub>*| - |*LIC(L<sub>n+1</sub>)*|

---

The last case can be proved by considering the list *L'<sub>n</sub>* obtained by removing *i<sub>n,1</sub>* from *L<sub>n+1</sub>*. In that case *LIC(L'<sub>n</sub>)* = *LIC(L<sub>n+1</sub>)* and thus:

> |*LIC(L'<sub>n</sub>)*| = |*LIC(L<sub>n</sub>)*| **(1)**

From there, we can sort *L'<sub>n</sub>* (which takes |*L'<sub>n</sub>*| - |*LIC(L'<sub>n</sub>*|  by the induction hypothesis. The previous equality **(1)** leads to the result.

**(*):** If *LIC(L<sub>n</sub>)* < 2, then *i<sub>n,2</sub>* doesn't exist. Just ignore the comparisons with it. In that case, only case 2 and case 3 apply... The result is still valid

Comment: I think he has no actual "swap" operation, it's more like a "remove from X" and "add at Y".

Comment: @JuanLopes Oh... Well in that case my answer is useless I guess :s

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to find the [longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) and move only elements that aren't inside it.

I can't prove it's optimal, but it is easy to prove it is correct and better than N swaps.

Here is a proof-of-concept in Python 2. I implemented it as a O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, but I'm pretty sure it can be reduced to O(n log n).

```
from operator import itemgetter

def LIS(V):
    T = [1]*(len(V))
    P = [-1]*(len(V))

    for i, v in enumerate(V):
        for j in xrange(i-1, -1, -1):
            if T[j]+1 > T[i] and V[j] <= V[i]:
                T[i] = T[j] + 1
                P[i] = j

    i, _ = max(enumerate(T), key=itemgetter(1))
    while i != -1:
        yield i
        i = P[i]

def complement(L, n):
    for a, b in zip(L, L[1:]+[n]):
        for i in range(a+1, b):
            yield i

def find_moves(V):
    n = len(V)
    L = list(LIS(V))[::-1]
    SV = sorted(range(n), key=lambda i:V[i])
    moves = [(x, SV.index(x)) for x in complement(L, n)]

    while len(moves):
        a, b = moves.pop()
        yield a, b
        moves = [(x-(x>a)+(x>b), y) for x, y in moves]


def make_and_print_moves(V):
    print 'Initial array:', V

    for a, b in find_moves(V):
        x = V.pop(a)
        V.insert(b, x)        
        print 'Move {} to {}. Result: {}'.format(a, b, V)
    print '***'

make_and_print_moves([1, 15, 2, 5, 10])

make_and_print_moves([4, 3, 2, 1])

make_and_print_moves([1, 2, 4, 3])
```

It outputs something like:

```
Initial array: [1, 15, 2, 5, 10]
Move 1 to 4. Result: [1, 2, 5, 10, 15]
***
Initial array: [4, 3, 2, 1]
Move 3 to 0. Result: [1, 4, 3, 2]
Move 3 to 1. Result: [1, 2, 4, 3]
Move 3 to 2. Result: [1, 2, 3, 4]
***
Initial array: [1, 2, 4, 3]
Move 3 to 2. Result: [1, 2, 3, 4]
***
```

Comment: I think it's optimal, it can be proved by induction if I'm not mistaken

Comment: this is would only help when sequence of numbers are not totally randoms.

Comment: @Techfist what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, this method would only give optimal answer when sequence does consist of increasing sub sequence, otherwise wont ??, but if his original question is only to sort number he has provided, this solution seems optimal.

Comment: If there is no increasing subsequence with length > 1 in the data (i.e. the array is sorted in descendent order), then there is no way of sorting the data with less than N-1 moves. @Rerito just prooved that.

Comment: The code has not been sufficiently tested.
Try `make_and_print_moves([4,5,6,1,2,3])` and it fails to sort the numbers correctly.